# How to import from libraries so that icons show up (webpack/jsoneditor)?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, webpack

I am using the library [jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor) with node/webpack and it works fine (functionality/ styling) except the images for the buttons do not appear.

I imported with

```
import JSONEditor from 'jsoneditor';
import 'jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.css';
import 'jsoneditor/dist/img/jsoneditor-icons.svg';
```

In webpack config I tried using the file-loader for svg as well as inline-svg-loader as David Bradshaw suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36035409/2232932)

There were no error messages in the console either. It looks like the icons are being loaded through the css files. Is there something special I have to do to use icon svg files with webpack?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use 'svg-inline-loader' first, but the icon of button can't be loaded.

Chrome Dev Tools show the button's style is `background: transparent url(<svg>...</svg>);`

So I change the loader to 'url-loader', and it is working now.
The style of button changes to `transparent url(/dev/assets/jsoneditor-icons.svg);`

Here is my config:

```
{
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=/assets/[name].[ext]'
}
```